# Is it possible to load SASS in Webpack without bundling fonts BUT with source maps?

Tags: sass, webpack

I don't want to bundle fonts and images but i need sourceMaps 
I have this config (irrelevant parts ommited):

```
output: {
   path: './build/',
   publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
   filename: '[name].js'
},

module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style','css?-url,sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap'] }   
  ]
}
```

With this config I get multiple errors in Chrome:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/
(index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I read a lot of answers and some solutions for similar problem:
1. get rid off 'sourceMap' - it works, and fonts are correctly displayed BUT ... no sourceMaps
2. change publicPath to URL - done it

I cannot find any solution that allows me load fonts outside bundle AND have CSS with sourceMaps...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The key to solution is ExtractTextPlugin that makes normal link tags instead of 'blobs' and all fonts work super, css are external (even better when they are large), source maps work. Here is my full config if anyone interested:

```
 var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack')
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            demo: ['./demo/index.ts', 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000'],
            lib: ['./src/js/index.js']
        },
        output: {
            path: './build/',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        debug: true,
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts' },
                { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: 'coffee' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url' },
                { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', query: { presets: ['es2015'] }, exclude: /node_modules/, },
                { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap') },
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap') },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/, loader: 'url' }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './demo'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", { allChunks: true })
        ]
    };
```